# JTable выводит троеточие в конце ячейки

Tags: java, jtable

[image: таблица]

Есть таблица JTable. В конце ячеек выводится троеточие. Почему? Ведь места с головой. Данные для таблицы берутся из БД. Как избавиться от троеточия?

Comment: Может test2222 заканчивается символом переноса строки?

Comment: да в том то и дело, что tes222 отличается от tes2222 только дополнительной двойкой... и сразу троеточие

Comment: У вас таблица из одного столбца? Обязательно JTable использовать? Сделайте столбец шире, или сделайте чтоб при наведении показывалась подсказка с полным текстом.

Comment: да сделал шире, просто для себя понять охота почему такая глупость происходит

Comment: Попробуйте при вычитке из БД использовать .trim()